# SonarQube not running on CentOS

Tags: sonarqube, virtual-machine

I'm currently trying to install sonarqube on my VM which runs CentOS.
I'm just running ./sonar.sh start or ./sonar.sh console but I get the following error:

```
Spawning intermediate process...
Spawning daemon process...
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Using tick timer.
server listening on port 32000.
Command[0] : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java
Command[1] : -Djava.awt.headless=true
Command[2] : -Xms3m
Command[3] : -Xmx32m
Command[4] : -Djava.library.path=./lib
Command[5] : -classpath
Command[6] : ../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-5.1.1.jar
Command[7] : -Dwrapper.key=YJaZZIwuLc49FoZw
Command[8] : -Dwrapper.port=32000
Command[9] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
Command[11] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE
Command[12] : -Dwrapper.pid=8925
Command[13] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
Command[14] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
Command[15] : -Dwrapper.service=TRUE
Command[16] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
Command[17] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
Command[18] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
Command[19] : org.sonar.application.App
Launching a JVM...
WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
Running a 64-bit JVM.
Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
Loading native library failed: libwrapper-linux-x86-64.so  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-linux-x86-64 in java.library.path
Loaded native library: libwrapper.so
Calling native initialization method.
Inside native WrapperManager initialization method
Java Version   : 1.8.0_40-b25 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation

Control event monitor thread started.
Startup runner thread started.
WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@4a574795, args[]) called by thread: main
Communications runner thread started.
Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
Opened Socket from 31000 to 32000
Send a packet KEY : YJaZZIwuLc49FoZw
handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31000])
accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31000
read a packet KEY : YJaZZIwuLc49FoZw
Got key from JVM: YJaZZIwuLc49FoZw
send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 0
send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Start Application.
send a packet START : start
Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 0
Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 0
Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Received a packet START : start
calling WrapperListener.start()
Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOP : 0
Startup runner thread stopped.
read a packet STOP : 0
JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
Sending stop signal to JVM
send a packet STOP : NULL
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOPPED : 0
read a packet STOPPED : 0
JVM signalled that it was stopped.
Closing socket.
socket read no code (closed?).
server listening on port 32001.
JVM exited normally.
Signal trapped.  Details:
  signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
returned from WrapperListener.start()
Send a packet STARTED : 
Server daemon shut down
<-- Wrapper Stopped
Spawning intermediate process...
Spawning daemon process...
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Using tick timer.
server listening on port 32000.
Command[0] : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java
Command[1] : -Djava.awt.headless=true
Command[2] : -Xms3m
Command[3] : -Xmx32m
Command[4] : -Djava.library.path=./lib
Command[5] : -classpath
Command[6] : ../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-5.1.1.jar
Command[7] : -Dwrapper.key=M_r8LVkidRlWI7_b
Command[8] : -Dwrapper.port=32000
Command[9] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
Command[11] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE
Command[12] : -Dwrapper.pid=9032
Command[13] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
Command[14] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
Command[15] : -Dwrapper.service=TRUE
Command[16] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
Command[17] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
Command[18] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
Command[19] : org.sonar.application.App
Launching a JVM...
WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
Running a 64-bit JVM.
Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
Loading native library failed: libwrapper-linux-x86-64.so  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-linux-x86-64 in java.library.path
Loaded native library: libwrapper.so
Calling native initialization method.
Inside native WrapperManager initialization method
Java Version   : 1.8.0_40-b25 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation

Control event monitor thread started.
Startup runner thread started.
WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@4a574795, args[]) called by thread: main
Communications runner thread started.
Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
Opened Socket from 31000 to 32000
Send a packet KEY : M_r8LVkidRlWI7_b
handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31000])
accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31000
read a packet KEY : M_r8LVkidRlWI7_b
Got key from JVM: M_r8LVkidRlWI7_b
send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 0
send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Start Application.
send a packet START : start
Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 0
Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 0
Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Received a packet START : start
calling WrapperListener.start()
Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOP : 0
Startup runner thread stopped.
read a packet STOP : 0
JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
Sending stop signal to JVM
send a packet STOP : NULL
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOPPED : 0
read a packet STOPPED : 0
JVM signalled that it was stopped.
Closing socket.
socket read no code (closed?).
server listening on port 32001.
JVM exited normally.
Signal trapped.  Details:
  signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
returned from WrapperListener.start()
Send a packet STARTED : 
Server daemon shut down
<-- Wrapper Stopped
Spawning intermediate process...
Spawning daemon process...
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Using tick timer.
server listening on port 32000.
Command[0] : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java
Command[1] : -Djava.awt.headless=true
Command[2] : -Xms3m
Command[3] : -Xmx32m
Command[4] : -Djava.library.path=./lib
Command[5] : -classpath
Command[6] : ../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-5.1.1.jar
Command[7] : -Dwrapper.key=90kxlGkfiFFf0qJi
Command[8] : -Dwrapper.port=32000
Command[9] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
Command[11] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE
Command[12] : -Dwrapper.pid=10211
Command[13] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
Command[14] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
Command[15] : -Dwrapper.service=TRUE
Command[16] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
Command[17] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
Command[18] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
Command[19] : org.sonar.application.App
Launching a JVM...
Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)
Signal trapped.  Details:
  signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
JVM process exited with a code of 1, setting the wrapper exit code to 1.
JVM exited while loading the application.
JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Using tick timer.
server listening on port 32000.
Command[0] : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java
Command[1] : -Djava.awt.headless=true
Command[2] : -Xms3m
Command[3] : -Xmx32m
Command[4] : -Djava.library.path=./lib
Command[5] : -classpath
Command[6] : ../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-5.1.1.jar
Command[7] : -Dwrapper.key=pQGEkNJknvC5D5wq
Command[8] : -Dwrapper.port=32000
Command[9] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
Command[11] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE
Command[12] : -Dwrapper.pid=10259
Command[13] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
Command[14] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
Command[15] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
Command[16] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
Command[17] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
Command[18] : org.sonar.application.App
Launching a JVM...
Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)
Signal trapped.  Details:
  signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
JVM process exited with a code of 1, setting the wrapper exit code to 1.
JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)
JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Any suggestions on what may be my problem?
I'll post my sonar.properties and wrapper.conf files below:

```
# This file must contain only ISO 8859-1 characters.
# See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)
#
# Property values can:
# - reference an environment variable, for example sonar.jdbc.url= ${env:SONAR_JDBC_URL}
# - be encrypted. See http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/settings-encryption.html


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT: the embedded H2 database is used by default. It is recommended for tests but not for
# production use. Supported databases are MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQLServer.

# User credentials.
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username=root
sonar.jdbc.password=

#----- Embedded Database (default)
# It does not accept connections from remote hosts, so the
# server and the analyzers must be executed on the same host.
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar

# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
sonar.embeddedDatabase.port=9092


#----- MySQL 5.x
# Only InnoDB storage engine is supported (not myISAM).
# Only the bundled driver is supported.
#sonar.jdbc.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance


#----- Oracle 10g/11g
# - Only thin client is supported
# - Only versions 11.2.* of Oracle JDBC driver are supported, even if connecting to lower Oracle versions.
# - The JDBC driver must be copied into the directory extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/
# - If you need to set the schema, please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE


#----- PostgreSQL 8.x/9.x
# If you don't use the schema named "public", please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar


#----- Microsoft SQLServer 2008/2012
# Only the bundled jTDS driver is supported.
# Collation must be case-sensitive (CS) and accent-sensitive (AS).
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor


#----- Connection pool settings
# The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated
# at the same time, or negative for no limit.
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=50

# The maximum number of connections that can remain idle in the
# pool, without extra ones being released, or negative for no limit.
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5

# The minimum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool,
# without extra ones being created, or zero to create none.
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2

# The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there
# are no available connections) for a connection to be returned before
# throwing an exception, or <= 0 to wait indefinitely.
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000

sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000



#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER

# Web server is executed in a dedicated Java process. By default heap size is 768Mb.
# Use the following property to customize JVM options.
#    Recommendations:
#
#    The HotSpot Server VM is recommended. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#    Set min and max memory (respectively -Xms and -Xmx) to the same value to prevent heap
#    from resizing at runtime.
#
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -server

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
sonar.web.context=/sonarqube

# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
sonar.web.port=9000

# The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.
# When this number has been reached, the server will not accept any more connections until
# the number of connections falls below this value. The operating system may still accept connections
# based on the sonar.web.connections.acceptCount property. The default value is 50 for each
# enabled connector.
sonar.web.http.maxThreads=50
#sonar.web.https.maxThreads=50

# The minimum number of threads always kept running. The default value is 5 for each
# enabled connector.
sonar.web.http.minThreads=5
#sonar.web.https.minThreads=5

# The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing
# threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.
# The default value is 25 for each enabled connector.
sonar.web.http.acceptCount=25
#sonar.web.https.acceptCount=25

# TCP port for incoming AJP connections. Disabled if value is -1. Disabled by default.
sonar.ajp.port=9000


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ELASTICSEARCH
# Elasticsearch is used to facilitate fast and accurate information retrieval.
# It is executed in a dedicated Java process.

# JVM options of Elasticsearch process
#    Recommendations:
#
#    Use HotSpot Server VM. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#    Set min and max memory (respectively -Xms and -Xmx) to the same value to prevent heap
#    from resizing at runtime.
#
sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Elasticsearch port. Default is 9001. Use 0 to get a free port.
# This port must be private and must not be exposed to the Internet.
sonar.search.port=9001


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# UPDATE CENTER

# Update Center requires an internet connection to request http://update.sonarsource.org
# It is enabled by default.
sonar.updatecenter.activate=true

# HTTP proxy (default none)
#http.proxyHost=
#http.proxyPort=

# NT domain name if NTLM proxy is used
#http.auth.ntlm.domain=

# SOCKS proxy (default none)
#socksProxyHost=
#socksProxyPort=

# proxy authentication. The 2 following properties are used for HTTP and SOCKS proxies.
#http.proxyUser=
#http.proxyPassword=


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOGGING

# Level of logs. Supported values are INFO, DEBUG and TRACE
sonar.log.level=TRACE

# Path to log files. Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Default is <installation home>/logs
sonar.path.logs=logs

# Rolling policy of log files
#    - based on time if value starts with "time:", for example by day ("time:yyyy-MM-dd")
#      or by month ("time:yyyy-MM")
#    - based on size if value starts with "size:", for example "size:10MB"
#    - disabled if value is "none".  That needs logs to be managed by an external system like logrotate.
sonar.log.rollingPolicy=time:yyyy-MM-dd

# Maximum number of files to keep if a rolling policy is enabled.
#    - maximum value is 20 on size rolling policy
#    - unlimited on time rolling policy. Set to zero to disable old file purging.
sonar.log.maxFiles=20

# Access log is the list of all the HTTP requests received by server. If enabled, it is stored
# in the file {sonar.path.logs}/access.log. This file follows the same rolling policy as for
# sonar.log (see sonar.log.rollingPolicy and sonar.log.maxFiles).
sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=true

# Format of access log. It is ignored if sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=false. Value is:
#    - "common" is the Common Log Format (shortcut for: %h %l %u %user %date "%r" %s %b)
#    - "combined" is another format widely recognized (shortcut for: %h %l %u [%t] "%r" %s %b "%i{Referer}" "%i{User-Agent}")
#    - else a custom pattern. See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#AccessPatternLayout
sonar.web.accessLogs.pattern=combined


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OTHERS

# Delay in seconds between processing of notification queue. Default is 60 seconds.
sonar.notifications.delay=60

# Paths to persistent data files (embedded database and search index) and temporary files.
# Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Defaults are respectively <installation home>/data and <installation home>/temp
sonar.path.data=data
sonar.path.temp=temp


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DEVELOPMENT - only for developers
# The following properties MUST NOT be used in production environments.

# Dev mode allows to reload web sources on changes and to restart server when new versions
# of plugins are deployed.
sonar.web.dev=true

# Path to webapp sources for hot-reloading of Ruby on Rails, JS and CSS (only core,
# plugins not supported).
sonar.web.dev.sources=/path/to/server/sonar-web/src/main/webapp

# Uncomment to enable the Elasticsearch HTTP connector, so that ES can be directly requested through
# http://lmenezes.com/elasticsearch-kopf/?location=http://localhost:9010
sonar.search.httpPort=9010
```

And the wrapper.conf file:

```
# Path to JVM executable. By default it must be available in PATH.
# Can be an absolute path, for example:
#wrapper.java.command=/path/to/my/jdk/bin/java
#wrapper.java.command=java
wrapper.java.command=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java

#
# DO NOT EDIT THE FOLLOWING SECTIONS
#


#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java
#********************************************************************
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../../lib/jsw/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../../lib/*.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.App
wrapper.java.initmemory=3
# Xmx can't be set to a lower value because of compatibility with Java 6
wrapper.java.maxmemory=32

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logs
#********************************************************************

wrapper.console.format=PM
wrapper.console.loglevel=TRACE
wrapper.logfile=../../logs/sonar.log
wrapper.logfile.format=M
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=TRACE

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10m

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=DEBUG

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Properties
#********************************************************************
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=SonarQube

# Disallow start of multiple instances of an application at the same time on Windows
wrapper.single_invocation=true

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name=SonarQube

# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=SonarQube

# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description=SonarQube

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false

#********************************************************************
# Forking Properties
#********************************************************************
wrapper.disable_restarts=TRUE
wrapper.ping.timeout=0
wrapper.shutdown.timeout=3000
wrapper.jvm_exit.timeout=3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error log "Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)" means that the path to java executable does not exist. Please check that /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java, as you configured in wrapper.conf, is correctly installed.

Comment: Sorry that was the third time i ran it and by then had tried switching machines.  I'll edit the post to only have the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Got it fixed now.  Found a CentOS/RedHat native distribution here: http://sonar-pkg.sourceforge.net/